# Add-action in function

Tags: actions

How can i get add_action to work in a function, I want to hide a few admin menu item but not make the user and editor.

```
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('themes.php');
    remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
    remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'check_username');
function check_username()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if($user && isset($user->user_email) && 'username@example.com' == $user->user_email)
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove those menu items in your `check_username` method.

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'check_username');
function check_username()
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'username@example.com' == $user->user_email ) {
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        remove_menu_page('themes.php');
        remove_menu_page('options-general.php');
        remove_menu_page('plugins.php');
    }
}
```

Your code doesn't work, because the `admin_init` action is invoked after `admin_menu`. Please see the [Action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) page in WordPress Codex.